# Is there any simple way to swap python dictionary key values where values are list

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any simple way to swap python dictionary key values where values are list
My dictionary is like following

```
d={1:[1,2,3,4],2:[2,3,4],5:[1,3,6,7]}
```

I want to generate a dictionary from it like following

```
a={1:[1,5],2:[1,2],3:[1,2,5],4:[1,2],6:[5],7:[5]}
```

I tested with reversed

```
dict(map(reversed, d.items())
```

It won't iterate and create keys with items in the list returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I am looking for any inline methods available for achieving this

Comment: Sounds like you want a directed graph.

Comment: Do you care what order the list elements are in?

Comment: Don't care of order

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
def revdict(d):
    r = {}
    for k in d:
        for v in d[k]:
            if v not in r:
                r[v] = [k]
            else:
                r[v].append(k)
    return r
```

Then you can do:

```
d={1:[1,2,3,4],2:[2,3,4],5:[1,3,6,7]}
a = revdict(d)
print(a)
```

If you want to avoid having to check for new keys, you can use a `defaultdict`, then always append.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach does not work, since here you aim to construct a dictionary:

```
{[1,2,3,4]: 1, [2,3,4]: 2, [1,3,6,7]: 5}
```

but since lists are unhashable, these can not be used as keys (and furthermore it is not what you intend to construct anyway).

You probably better use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for k, vs in d.items():
    for v in vs:
        result[v].append(k)
```

after this opertion, `result` is a `defaultdict` (a subclass of the *vanilla* `dict`) which maps items in the list of values to keys (that contained that value). Like:

```
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [1, 5], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 2, 5], 4: [1, 2], 6: [5], 7: [5]})
```

You can optionally use:

```
result = dict(result)
```

to create a new dictionary with these values (and thus drop the `defaultdict`).

Mind that:

- since most Python interpreters do not order the dictionary (it is definitely not a hard assumption you can make), the order of the elements in the list might be different; and
- the items in the lists in your dictionary `d` should be *hashable*.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really suitable for a one-liner; you are oversimplifying what you need to do by calling it a simple reversal.

A real reversal would simply map values to keys instead of keys to values, which you can do (with the slight but necessary change of lists to tuples):

```
>>> print dict((tuple(d[k]), k) for k in d)
{(1, 3, 6, 7): 5, (2, 3, 4): 2, (1, 2, 3, 4): 1}
```

What you want is far more complicated, and is commonly called a transposition of the dict.

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig
from itertools import groupby

transposed_dict = dict((k, map(ig(1), v)) 
                       for k, v in groupby(
                                      sorted((nk, k) for k in d for nk in d[k]),
                                             key=ig(0)))
```

There's nothing particularly simple about this, although conceptually it isn't too bad:

1. `(nk, k) for k in d for nk in d[k]` creates an expanded association list from the dictionary, with the keys and values inverted.
2. `groupby` collects all the tuples with a common first element
3. `(k, map(ig(1), v))` collects the tuples with a common first element into a single tuple: `(1,1), (1,2) => (1, [1,2])`.
4. The tuples from step 3 are used to build the new dictionary.

You are far better off, however, using a simple 3-line `for` loop as shown by Willem Van Onsem; the essence of that loop is in the generator expression used by `sorted`; everything else is just dealing with the attempt to avoid mutable variables. Not everything should (or can) be reduced to a simple one-liner.